# require("lodash") - require is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, lodash

I saw this lodash-thing once and thought it would be nice to use. So I try now for days, but can't get it running. Please be patient as I'm a noob in this thing.

I have `npm install lodash --save` .. so it is in my `node_modules` and in my `package.json` I have:

```
"dependencies": {
"del": "^2.2.2",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.15.0"
},
```

so now, when I do `const _ = require("lodash");` it should work, right?
If not, what did I forgot?

would be nice if someone could explain it to me. I'm watching and reading tutorials for days now, but whatever I try, I can't get it working.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? (Are you able to `require()` other modules in the same project?)

Comment: yes .. it says `ReferenceError: require is not defined 

const l = require("lodash");` .. I haven't tried yet, lodash is the first thing ever I would like to use.. but I do require stuff in my gulpfile.js, and that works

Comment: Are you using `require()` in server-side JS or client-side (browser) JS?

Comment: I'm using it on client side. I know it is a server-thing,. so I `npm install browserify`, but can't get it how to use :/

Comment: It's not a server thing. Read the [documentation](https://lodash.com/#download) and include it in the HTML file like any other JS library.

Comment: i have red multiple times now, that require is a server thing.. by the way, when I should include it like a normal script to my HTML-file, why should I install the node-package then?

Comment: To use Lodash client-side, just include `<script src="lodash.js"></script>` (with the appropriate path) in your page. Use `require()` when you want to use Lodash server-side. You shouldn't need to install the package in Node if you aren't using it server-side.

Comment: You *shouldn't* install the Node package if you're using it client-side. Just download and include the JS file. NPM is for managing your Node libraries, not your client-side libraries. (You *can* download it with NPM if you want to use it as a package manager, but at this point it's probably better to not go that route.)

Comment: Run the command `browserify main.js -o "/public/js/bundle.js"` where main.js is your client-side javascript where you do `require(lodash)` and the `-o` argument is your output folder, typically a folder accessible from your webpage. Browserify will bundle all javascript needed by this file to the output file, which will be downloaded later on client side.

Comment: @dth .. thanks dude!! :) .. that was exaxtly what I was searching for!! .,. thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

You should get it going with adding `lodash` in your `package.json` and then doing `npm install`

```
{
  "name" : "myApp",
  "main" : "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    . . .
    "lodash"          : "~4.15.0"
  }
}
```

And doing the following in your `server.js`

```
. . .
var _ = require('lodash');
. . .
//When doing ._ calls lodash, defined globally
global._ = _;
. . .
```

And then, in any `.js` file in your back-end

```
var array = [];
//Checks if an Array or an Object is Empty
if(_.isEmpty(array)){
   doSomething();
}
```

Or, if you do not want to use it globally, just do a `require` of `lodash` where you need it

```
var _. = require('lodash');
```

If you want to use `lodash` in your front-end, supposing you are using `bower`, you need to include `lodash` in your `bower.json`, do `bower install` and including `lodash.js` in your `index` by hand or using a tool to inject it like `Gulp` or `Grunt`.

I hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.
I changed

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.187", ...
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.14.187", ...
```

in the package.json file.